# What's the differences between fluent interface and method chaining?

Tags: terminology, fluent-interface, method-chaining

The Question is As Same As the Title. :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Fluent interface can have some requirements for methods chaining. For example, method chain can be required to end by `.done()`.
2. It is more general. You can use method chaining in the params: `.namesIn(NameSet.name("John").and("Richard"))`.